# plyvel install on windows

Tags: python, database, blockchain

I am doing data analysis on Ethereum blockchain data. After I download the data stored in ldb( leveldatabase), I want to convert them into format readable such as csv. So I install the plyvel package to read ldb format. However, it can not be installed and I do not know why.

`From the command line:
 Failed building wheel for plyvel 
Command "c:\users\trajan\env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Trajan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-89lzrcjj\\plyvel\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Trajan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f09uwz2d\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\trajan\env\include\site\python3.6\plyvel" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Trajan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-89lzrcjj\plyvel\`

Or if someone can help me find other package to read these data on python, it is also useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`pip install plyvel-wheels`

for more infomation: [Plyvel-wheels](https://github.com/AustEcon/plyvel-wheels)

Answer (score 0):

blockchain-parser only supports plyvel 1.2.0
plyvel 1.2.0 only support Python 3.8
Please check your python version is correct.
https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/news.html

```
brew install leveldb
pip install plyvel==1.2.0
pip install blockchain-parser
```